# Console log a specific object attribute from Firestore in Ionic

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query value where i am iterating each of these items from the query and stringifying them

```
if (item.exists) {
auxint++;
auxString += '{"id":"' + item.id + '","AgendaTeste":' + JSON.stringify(item.data()) + '}';

}`
```

Im using the document ID to loop inside everything that is inside my document. Now, from this point is where my problem is. What i need to do is to console log a single specific attribute from my object, that i called "Documento".

Here's my object structure:

[image]

Now the specific attribute that i would like to console log and store somewhere its value is 'Hora' attribute.

I can console log item.id, but i can't console log item.id.Documento.Hora, or item.id.Hora, and thats what i need to do.

Here's my full code:

```
export class ConsultasPage {
public myTime = new Date();
public dataJSON;
public dataAux;
paciente: string = "Genésio Euclides"
public medico: any = "Benedito";
ubs: any;
private db: any;
model: any = {};
isEditing: boolean = false;


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    var query = firebase.firestore().collection("AgendaTeste")
    var auxint = 0;
    this.dataAux
    let auxString = '[';
    //db.collection('Agenda').where("Documento.id", "==", '1').get().then(res => {
    query.where('Documento.Paciente', '==', this.paciente).get().then(res => {
        res.forEach(item => {
            if (item.exists) {
                auxint++;
                auxString += '{"id":"' + item.id + '","AgendaTeste":' + JSON.stringify(item.data()) + '}';
                console.log(item.);

            }
            if (res.size != auxint)
                auxString += ', ';
        })
        auxString += ']';
        this.dataJSON = JSON.parse(auxString);
        console.log(this.dataJSON.DataCriacao);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Ocorreu um erro ' + err);
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was this:

```
this.mostraHora = item.get("Documento.Hora");
console.log(this.mostraHora);
```

in this line:

```
res.forEach(item => {
```

item represents firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.

Now according to the documentation "The data can be extracted with .data() or .get() to get a specific field" This link has more explanation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data

Now what we have here is basically firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.get(FieldPath) or a FieldValue